# Exception: java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment. in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am new apache-spark. I have tested some application in spark standalone mode.but I want to run application yarn mode.I am running apache-spark 2.1.0 in windows.Here is My code

```
c:\spark>spark-submit2 --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-cores 4 --jars C:\DependencyJars\spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11-2.0.3.jar,C:\DependencyJars\scalaj-http_2.11-2.3.0.jar,C:\DependencyJars\config-1.3.1.jar,C:\DependencyJars\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar --conf spark.driver.userClasspathFirst=true --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=C:\DependencyJars\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar --conf spark.executor.userClasspathFirst=true --class "GeoLogConsumerRT" C:\sbtazure\target\scala-2.11\azuregeologproject_2.11-1.0.jar
```

**EXCEPTION: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment. in spark**

so from searching website. I have created a folder name Hadoop_CONF_DIR and place hive site.xml in it and pointed as environment variable, after that i have run spark-submit then I have got

**connection refused exception**
I think i could not configure yarn mode set up properly.Could anyone help me for solving this issue? do I need to install Hadoop and yarn separately?I want to run my application in pseudo distributed mode.Kindly help me to configure yarn mode in windows thanks

Answer (score 24):

You need to export two variables `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and `YARN_CONF_DIR` to make your configurations file visible to yarn. Use below code  in .bashrc file if you are using linux.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

In windows you need to set environment variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen  Linux config before but currently, i am working on windows.  I have winutils folder which is my Hadoop home actually. and it is my Hadoop home environmental variable. are you referring that I will set  HADOOP_CONF_DIR , YARN_CONF_DIR as environment variable which will point winutils's bin folder ?

Comment: this one doesn't work for me. I solved this according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703235/when-running-with-master-yarn-either-hadoop-conf-dir-or-yarn-conf-dir-must-be?rq=1), which says modify the `spark_env.sh` file in spark conf folder

Comment: What is the minimal change to make this work? DO YOU NEED THAT DIR TO EXIST?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running spark using Yarn then you better need to add this to `spark-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```