# When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run Spark using yarn and I am running into this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` must be set in the environment.

I am not sure where the "environment" is (what specific file?).  I tried using:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

in the bash_profile, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: did you confirm if the environments are set by doing `echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR`?

Answer (score 16):

While running spark using Yarn, you need to add following line in to `spark-env.sh`

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

Note: check $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop is correct one in your environment. And spark-env.sh contains export of HADOOP_HOME as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows environment, open file load-spark-env.cmd in the Spark bin folder and add the following line:

```
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop
```

Answer (score -2):

## just an update to answer by Shubhangi,

```
 cd $SPARK_HOME/bin
 sudo nano load-spark-env.sh
```

## add below lines , save and exit

export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop"

export YARN_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop"