# Connecting to remote Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing, apache-spark-standalone

I'm having problem connecting to a spark cluster remotely from jupyter notebook. It works fine locally.

Method 1:

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('Pi').setMaster('spark://my-cluster:7077')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This returns successfully. when i then try to run the Pi example

```
partitions = 3
n = 1000 * partitions

def f(_):
    x = random() * 2 - 1
    y = random() * 2 - 1
    return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / n))
```

it just keeps on running forever with the error in console:

```
warn taskschedulerimpl: initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster ui to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

In the cluster ui the job is set as "running" and the workers are alive however it seems no work is actually being done.

```
Worker Id   Address State   Cores   Memory
worker-20180417174137-192.168.1.13-43697    192.168.1.13:43697  ALIVE   4 (4 Used)  6.8 GB (1024.0 MB Used)
worker-20180417174137-192.168.1.14-38778    192.168.1.14:38778  ALIVE   4 (4 Used)  6.8 GB (1024.0 MB Used)
worker-20180417174137-192.168.1.15-35776    192.168.1.15:35776  ALIVE   4 (4 Used)  6.8 GB (1024.0 MB Used)
```

So resources should exist more than enough for this simple job anyway. So what could be causing the issue here?

Due to remarks in comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662596/spark-check-your-cluster-ui-to-ensure-that-workers-are-registered) question about the exact same issue I tried to connect to the cluster with yarn as master.

```
conf.set('spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address', 'my-cluster:8032')
conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.default.name', 'hdfs://my-cluster:9000')
conf.set('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client')
```

This resulted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703235/when-running-with-master-yarn-either-hadoop-conf-dir-or-yarn-conf-dir-must-be) issue and I applied the answer accordingly. initiating the context then with

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Simply does not return, blocks endlessly until manually cancelled. I tried this in my Ubuntu VM and then thought maybe it's a network issue to the VM and installed spark in the host Windows 7 system too with the exact same result. So how to I successfully connect to the cluster and launch applications?

Comment: Setting spark driver host and port and then adding the host ip into each nodes hosts file + adding firewall rule to drivers routers makes this specific error go away so yeah it was a duplicate question. However it still fails to work and no progress is made.