# How can I run spark in headless mode in my custom version on HDP?

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, headless, ambari, hdp

How can I run spark in headless mode?
Currently, I am executing spark on a HDP 2.6.4 (i.e. 2.2 is installed by default) on the cluster.
I have downloaded a spark 2.4.1 Scala 2.11 release in headless mode (i.e. no hadoop jars are built in) from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. The exact name is: pre-built with scala 2.11 and user provided hadoop

Now when trying to run I follow: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export SPARK_HOME=/home/<<my_user>>/development/software/spark_no_provided_hadoop
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue <<my_yarn_queue>>
```

Unfortunately, it fails to start:

```
19/05/01 07:12:23 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/05/01 07:12:38 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
19/05/01 07:12:38 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1555489055691_64276 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1555489055691_64276_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1

When looking at the logs for details I see:
Log Type: prelaunch.err

launch_container.sh: line 30: $PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez/conf:$PWD/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__: bad substitution
```

So:

```
/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar: bad substitution
```

is the cause (and similar to https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/23699/bad-substitution-error-running-spark-on-yarn.html), but this is completely inside Ambari's management domain. How can I work around it to run a more recent version of spark (2.4.x) on the existing 2.6.x HDP plattform?

### edit

Assuming I passed a wrong configuration directory for `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, it is unset. But then:

```
When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
```

so it must be passed. Could it be, that I am passing the wrong value?
According to [Exception: java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment. in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434308/exception-java-lang-exception-when-running-with-master-yarn-either-hadoop-co) could be correct. For me, no HADOOP_HOME is set by default.

Even when setting to: `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf`, the same bad substitution error remains.

NOTE: some interesting steps:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/244059/steps-to-install-supplementary-spark-on-hdp-cluste.html, but not for the headless edition
- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85757/how-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/23699/bad-substitution-error-running-spark-on-yarn.html is the solution:

```
cd /usr/hdp                                                                                                                                  
ls
2.6.xxx  current  share
```

So for me:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --queue <<my_queue>>--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.xxx' --conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=2.6.xxx'
```

works