# spark 3.x on HDP 3.1 in headless mode with hive - hive tables not found

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform, hive-metastore

How can I configure Spark 3.x on HDP 3.1 using headless (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html) version of spark to interact with hive?

First, I have downloaded and unzipped the headless spark 3.x:

```
cd ~/development/software/spark-3.0.0-bin-without-hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop --config /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf classpath)
 
ls /usr/hdp # note version ad add it below and replace 3.1.x.x-xxx with it

./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --queue myqueue --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=3.1.x.x-xxx' --conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=3.1.x.x-xxx' --conf spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive --files /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml

spark.sql("show databases").show
// only showing default namespace, existing hive tables are missing
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+

spark.conf.get("spark.sql.catalogImplementation")
res2: String = in-memory # I want to see hive here - how? How to add hive jars onto the classpath?
```

### NOTE

This is an updated version of [How can I run spark in headless mode in my custom version on HDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931970/how-can-i-run-spark-in-headless-mode-in-my-custom-version-on-hdp) for Spark 3.x ond HDP 3.1 and [custom spark does not find hive databases when running on yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233795/custom-spark-does-not-find-hive-databases-when-running-on-yarn).

Furthermore: I am aware of the problems of ACID hive tables in spark. For now, I simply want to be able to see the existing databases

### edit

We must get the hive jars onto the class path. Trying as follows:

```
 export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib*:${SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH}"
```

And now using spark-sql:

```
./bin/spark-sql --master yarn --queue myqueue--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=3.1.x.x-xxx' --conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions='-Dhdp.version=3.1.x.x-xxx' --conf spark.hadoop.metastore.catalog.default=hive --files /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml
```

fails with:

```
Error: Failed to load class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.
Failed to load main class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.
```

I.e. the line: `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib*:${SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH}"`, had no effect (same issue if not set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above and [custom spark does not find hive databases when running on yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233795/custom-spark-does-not-find-hive-databases-when-running-on-yarn) the Hive JARs are needed. They are not supplied in the headless version.

I was unable to retrofit these.

Solution: instead of worrying: simply use the spark build with Hadoop 3.2 (on HDP 3.1)